# Defective SUMPRODUCT/COUNTIF formula : incorrect count

Tags: excel, countif, sumproduct

So here is the formula I'm using to count the number of unique numeric entries within a range of cells :

SUMPRODUCT(1 / COUNTIF(I8205:I8220, I8205:I8220)

Where, I8205:I8220 may or may not contain filtered cells.

Please click the link to review the formula and the excel snip.

The main issue : The formula typically works well. In this instance, it returned the incorrect count. Manually you will see the total is 14, however the formula returns 13. Help me figure out what went wrong =/[snip of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgrSY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula is giving correct result as per your data. Please check carefully rows `8208,8212,8213,8217,8218,8220` . These rows have duplicate instances. So 16 rows -3 rows comes 13 which is correct answer.

Edit : Hope screen shot will clarify you. I sorted the relevant data in an adjacent column. Duplicate instances are shaded.
[image: countif duplicates]

Comment: Bah, beat me to it, @Grace PT , your duplicate entry values are: SHPX214915, SHPX214898, SHPX214876

Comment: Ha Ha =) Thank you both